# Unity Online Multiplayer

Tags: unity, multiplayer, online

I have searched this on the internet, but I didn't get any clear answers. My question is - Can I implement an online multiplayer functionality in Unity personal edition? Also without spending any money.

Comment: as the main site directly lists the service, and quotes "Unity Personal: free: 20 concurrent players", I am voting down for lack of research.

Answer (score 4):

[According to the main Unity website](https://unity3d.com/services/multiplayer), yes; you can implement free online multiplayer functionality in the personal edition, with up to 20 concurrent players.

Comment: If look under it, it says 0.49/GB and has a bill calculator. What is that then.

Comment: @AJ123, it *literally* says "20 concurrent seats, free". It also goes on to detail the *extra* seats you get, *if you pay*.

Comment: @AJ123, the "bill" you reference is for "as much traffic as you need" (i.e. if you need more than the maximum quoted 200 concurrent players for $125, you can opt to pay for the *usage* and have potentially infinite concurrent players)

Comment: Have a look at PlayFab... might help you and has a free tier. Has multiplayer and integration with Unity3d

Comment: what about photon? Can we use that in free edition.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the [multiplayer service](https://unity3d.com/services/multiplayer) that Unity itself offers, you can also create your own, removing the limitations of the free service. Depending on what kind of a system you go with, you can create your own master server where the actual game servers announce themselves at and where the actual game client retrieves a list of servers. This would require you to have extensive knowledge about networking code in general and would be a bigger task then implementing the default service.

Comment: This isn't really a "not spending any money" solution. You won't get a server for free. Although renting server capacity has become extremely cheap and easy recently due to all the cloud server providers (aws, azure, etc.).